# Trying to access the modem (not router) configuration on my network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a wireless network that consists of a dual-band router and the modem that Comcast supplied to me. I'm trying to figure out how to access its configuration settings so that I can do things like remotely restart it. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Model numbers?  What port of the *"dual-band router"* does the modem plug in to (the WAN or a LAN port)?  The modem might have a built-in router that is bridged, which will make its web server inaccessible when connected to the *"dual-band router's"* WAN port. One scenario is that you may have to disconnect the wireless router and connect a PC directly to the modem.

Answer (score 0):

when you say remotely, do you mean from the WAN side? that will not be possible without special ISP software which you will not be able to access. allowing this would let attackers easily perform denial of service attacks on entire subnets with a simple HTTP request.

from the LAN side, this is possible if your modem and ISP configuration allow it.
Check this list to determine the IP address of the lan side of the modem:
http://www.dslreports.com/faq/7363
most ISPs use 192.168.100.1 and just point a web browser at it.